# Pydub send raw data to icecast server

Tags: python, pyaudio, icecast, msys, pydub

Well, this code works:

```
with requests.get("https://impradio.bytemasters.gr/8002/LIVE", stream=True) as peradio:
    for chunk in peradio.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        self.s.send(chunk)
        self.s.sync()
```

but this doesn't

```
self.stream.write(final_slice.raw_data)
active_connection_found = False
for connection in self.connections:
    if connection["status"]=="connected":               
        connection["connection"].send(final_slice.raw_data)
        connection["connection"].sync()
        active_connection_found = True
if active_connection_found==False:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

there is no error but I can't hear any music (loading) on the browser.

So, I tried to write the final_slice to a temp file and then to send the f.read() bytes to the Icecast server.
Works, but there is a big sound delay (from final_slice to final_slice), and the program slows down a lot.

```
active_connection_found = False
send_data = io.BytesIO()
final_slice.export(send_data,format="mp3")
send_data = send_data.getvalue()
for connection in self.connections:
    if connection["status"]=="connected":           
        connection["connection"].send(send_data)
        connection["connection"].sync()
        active_connection_found = True
if active_connection_found==False:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The up code works but with low quality (lug delay).

What can i do?

**Edit:** The bitrate i am trying to use is 128Kbps.

The pyaudio Quality of Service settings are:

```
#QoS settings
self.bit_rate = 128*1024 #128 kb/sec #never used this variable at the code.
self.packet_time = 93 #125 msec
self.packet_size = int(16384/4)
#self.new_sample_rate = 32768
self.new_sample_rate = 44100
        
self.format = pyaudio.paInt16
self.channels = 2
```

**Edit2:** I tried to send `final_slice._data` but same result.

---

This in the run method of QThread

```
    def run(self):  
        for output_device in self.output_devices:
            if(self.primary_output_device_name==output_device[2]):
                self.output_device_index = output_device[1]
                for input_device in self.input_devices:
                    if(self.input_device_name==input_device[2]):
                        self.input_device_index = input_device[1]
                        
                        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=2,rate=self.new_sample_rate,input=True,input_device_index=self.input_device_index,output=True,output_device_index=self.output_device_index,frames_per_buffer=self.packet_size)
                        self.stream.start_stream()
        while(True):                        
            deck_1_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            if self.deck_1["play-status"]=="playing":
                if self.deck_1["current-duration-milliseconds"]>self.deck_1["total-duration-milliseconds"]:
                    self.deck_1["play-status"] = "stopped"
                    self.deck_1_status_signal.emit("stopped")
                    self.deck_1["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.deck_1["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                if self.deck_1["play-status"]=="playing":
                    if self.deck_1["player-list-item"]["type"] != "retransmitions":
                        if(self.deck_1["normalize"]==False or self.deck_1["normalize"]==0):
                            if((self.deck_1["chunk-number"]+1)*(self.packet_time)20:
                        deck_1_slice = effects.high_pass_filter(deck_1_slice, self.deck_1["low-frequency"])
                    if self.deck_1["high-frequency"]>20000:
                        deck_1_slice = effects.low_pass_filter(deck_1_slice, self.deck_1["high-frequency"])
                    if(self.deck_1["volume"]==0):
                        self.db_volume = -200
                    else:   
                        self.db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.deck_1["volume"]/100)
                    deck_1_slice = deck_1_slice+self.db_volume
                else:
                    self.deck_1["chunk-number"] = 0
                    deck_1_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            elif self.deck_1["play-status"] == "stopped":
                    self.deck_1["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.deck_1["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                    deck_1_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            
            #deck_1_volume_strength
            average_data_value = deck_1_slice.max
            normalized_value = abs(average_data_value)/deck_1_slice.max_possible_amplitude
            if normalized_value>1:
                normalized_value = 1
            self.deck_1_volume_signal.emit(normalized_value)
            
            
            #deck 2
            deck_2_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            if self.deck_2["play-status"]=="playing":
                if self.deck_2["current-duration-milliseconds"]>self.deck_2["total-duration-milliseconds"]:
                    self.deck_2["play-status"] = "stopped"
                    self.deck_2["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.deck_2["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                    self.deck_2_status_signal.emit("stopped")
                if self.deck_2["play-status"]=="playing":
                    if self.deck_2["player-list-item"]["type"] != "retransmitions":
                        if(self.deck_2["normalize"]==False or self.deck_2["normalize"]==0):
                            if((self.deck_2["chunk-number"]+1)*(self.packet_time)20:
                        deck_2_slice = effects.high_pass_filter(deck_2_slice, self.deck_2["low-frequency"])
                    if self.deck_2["high-frequency"]>20000:
                        deck_2_slice = effects.low_pass_filter(deck_2_slice, self.deck_2["high-frequency"])
                    if(self.deck_2["volume"]==0):
                        self.db_volume = -200
                    else:   
                        self.db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.deck_2["volume"]/100)
                    deck_2_slice = deck_2_slice+self.db_volume
                else:
                    self.deck_2["chunk-number"] = 0
                    deck_2_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            elif self.deck_2["play-status"] == "stopped":
                    self.deck_2["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.deck_2["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                    deck_2_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            
            #deck_2_volume_strength
            average_data_value = deck_2_slice.max
            normalized_value = abs(average_data_value)/deck_2_slice.max_possible_amplitude
            if normalized_value>1:
                normalized_value = 1
            self.deck_2_volume_signal.emit(normalized_value)
            
            #music clip deck
            music_clip_deck_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            if self.music_clip_deck["play-status"]=="playing":
                if self.music_clip_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"]>self.music_clip_deck["total-duration-milliseconds"]:
                    self.music_clip_deck["play-status"] = "stopped"
                    self.music_clip_deck["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.music_clip_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                    self.music_clip_deck_status_signal.emit("stopped")
                if self.music_clip_deck["play-status"]=="playing":
                    
                    if(self.music_clip_deck["normalize"]==False or self.music_clip_deck["normalize"]==0):
                        if((self.music_clip_deck["chunk-number"]+1)*(self.packet_time)20:
                        music_clip_deck_slice = effects.high_pass_filter(music_clip_deck_slice, self.music_clip_deck["low-frequency"])
                    if self.music_clip_deck["high-frequency"]>20000:
                        music_clip_deck_slice = effects.low_pass_filter(music_clip_deck_slice, self.music_clip_deck["high-frequency"])
                    if(self.music_clip_deck["volume"]==0):
                        self.db_volume = -200
                    else:   
                        self.db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.music_clip_deck["volume"]/100)
                    music_clip_deck_slice = music_clip_deck_slice+self.db_volume
                else:
                    self.music_clip_deck["chunk-number"] = 0
                    music_clip_deck_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            elif self.deck_2["play-status"] == "stopped":
                    self.music_clip_deck["chunk-number"] = 0
                    self.music_clip_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                    music_clip_deck_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
            
            #music_clip_volume_strength
            average_data_value = music_clip_deck_slice.max
            normalized_value = abs(average_data_value)/music_clip_deck_slice.max_possible_amplitude
            if normalized_value>1:
                normalized_value = 1
            self.music_clip_deck_volume_signal.emit(normalized_value)
            
            
            #speackers deck
            if self.speackers_deck["play-status"]=="playing":
                microphone_data = self.stream.read(self.packet_size)
                microphone_slice = AudioSegment(microphone_data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=self.new_sample_rate, channels=2)
                #microphone_slice = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(microphone_slice, microphone_slice)
                if self.speackers_deck["pan"]!=0:
                    microphone_slice = microphone_slice.pan(self.speackers_deck["pan"])
                if self.speackers_deck["low-frequency"]>20:
                    microphone_slice = effects.high_pass_filter(microphone_slice, self.speackers_deck["low-frequency"])
                if self.speackers_deck["high-frequency"]>20000:
                    microphone_slice = effects.low_pass_filter(microphone_slice, self.speackers_deck["high-frequency"])
                if(self.speackers_deck["volume"]==0):
                    self.db_volume = -200
                else:   
                    self.db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.speackers_deck["volume"]/100)
                microphone_slice = microphone_slice+self.db_volume
                #normalize
                if(self.speackers_deck["normalize"]==True or self.speackers_deck["normalize"]==1):
                    microphone_slice = self.normalize_method(microphone_slice,0.1)
            else:
                self.speackers_deck["chunk-number"] = 0
                self.speackers_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"] = 0
                microphone_slice = AudioSegment.empty()
                
            
            #microphone_volume_strength
            average_data_value = microphone_slice.max
            normalized_value = abs(average_data_value)/microphone_slice.max_possible_amplitude
            if normalized_value>1:
                normalized_value = 1
            self.speackers_deck_volume_signal.emit(normalized_value)
            
            if(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                final_slice = self.silent_segment
            else:
                if(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = microphone_slice
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = music_clip_deck_slice
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_2_slice
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(deck_2_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(music_clip_deck_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_2_slice.overlay(music_clip_deck_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_2_slice.overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = music_clip_deck_slice.overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)==0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(deck_2_slice).overlay(music_clip_deck_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)==0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(deck_2_slice).overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)==0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_2_slice.overlay(music_clip_deck_slice).overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)==0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(music_clip_deck_slice).overlay(microphone_slice)
                elif(len(deck_1_slice)!=0 and len(deck_2_slice)!=0 and len(music_clip_deck_slice)!=0 and len(microphone_slice)!=0):
                    final_slice = deck_1_slice.overlay(deck_2_slice).overlay(music_clip_deck_slice).overlay(microphone_slice)
                    
            #final slice settings
            if self.general_deck["pan"]!=0:
                final_slice = final_slice.pan(self.general_deck["pan"])
            if self.general_deck["low-frequency"]>20:
                final_slice = effects.high_pass_filter(final_slice, self.general_deck["low-frequency"])
            if self.general_deck["high-frequency"]>20000:
                final_slice = effects.low_pass_filter(final_slice, self.general_deck["high-frequency"])
            if(self.general_deck["volume"]==0):
                self.db_volume = -200
            else:   
                self.db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.general_deck["volume"]/100)
            final_slice = final_slice+self.db_volume
            #normalize
            if(self.general_deck["normalize"]==True or self.general_deck["normalize"]==1):
                final_slice = self.normalize_method(final_slice,0.1)
            
            #final_slice_volume_strength
            average_data_value = final_slice.max
            normalized_value = abs(average_data_value)/final_slice.max_possible_amplitude
            self.general_deck_volume_signal.emit(normalized_value)
            
            if self.deck_1["play-status"]=="playing":
                self.deck_1["chunk-number"] +=1
                self.deck_1["current-duration-milliseconds"] += self.packet_time
                self.deck_1_duration_signal.emit(self.deck_1["current-duration-milliseconds"])
            if self.deck_2["play-status"]=="playing":
                self.deck_2["chunk-number"] +=1
                self.deck_2["current-duration-milliseconds"] += self.packet_time
                self.deck_2_duration_signal.emit(self.deck_2["current-duration-milliseconds"])
            if self.music_clip_deck["play-status"]=="playing":
                self.music_clip_deck["chunk-number"] +=1
                self.music_clip_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"] += self.packet_time
                self.music_clip_deck_duration_signal.emit(self.music_clip_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"])
            if self.speackers_deck["play-status"]=="playing":
                self.speackers_deck["chunk-number"] +=1
                self.speackers_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"] += self.packet_time
                self.speackers_deck_duration_signal.emit(self.speackers_deck["current-duration-milliseconds"])
            if self.record_status=="recording":
                try:
                    self.output_file.writeframesraw(final_slice.raw_data)
                except:
                    pass
            
            #self.stream.write(final_slice.raw_data)
            active_connection_found = False
            send_data = io.BytesIO()
            t1 = time.time()
            final_slice.export(send_data,format="mp3")
            send_data = send_data.getvalue()
            t2 = time.time()
            print(t2-t1)
            for connection in self.connections:
                if connection["status"]=="connected":
                    
                    connection["connection"].send(send_data)
                    connection["connection"].sync()
                    active_connection_found = True
            if active_connection_found==False:
                time.sleep(0.01)
```

I tried to record some seconds to wav format, and the record Quality is good.

But when i connect to Icecast server, the sound either from the application either from the browser is interrupted. :/

Edit: If I change the packet_time to be 744 msec. Almost Everything work perfect. The problem now is in the microphone voice.

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Comment: Does your server to which you are sending data show your connection? In case of Icecast there should be a mount point displayed. If not - check that piece of code that connects to Icecast and authenticates. If connection is ok but the sound does not play - I just usually write all the stream that I am sending to a file and try to play it with VLC to see if it is ok.

Comment: @AlexParamonov the connection is ok I can see the mount point, and if I record the stream I can hear music. I believe that I may encode the raw data before send it to the server.

Comment: So I think that I send wav data, and icecast is waiting mp3 data.

Comment: In this case you need to encode your stream into mp3 and set "Content Type: audio/mpeg" for your stream.